# When using VPN on a WiFi network, can the traffic of other non-VPN computers on the WiFi be monitored?

Tags: wifi, vpn

Let's say I am using a WiFi connection and am connected through VPN to a private network.

Would the computer using VPN be able to monitor the traffic of other computers connected to the same WiFi, but without using VPN.

The answer is unclear to me as the VPN connection provides an encrypted tunnel to the private network, out of reach of the other computers on the WiFi (or rather: encrypted beyond recognition, hopefully), but I'm not sure whether those computers "outside of the tunnel" are reachable to the VPN connected computer ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a "tunnel" actually only the connection between you and the Server is encrypted. This is calles a remote-access-VPN

However there is also a thing called site-to-site VPN which is used to connect whole network with ech other in an encrypted way.

I assume you have some sort of client software which usually means you are using the remote access vpn.

Your computer is able to see other computers traffic in a wifi scenario, thats the reason you are using encryption.